# Ruby 'unless' keyword

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm unsure of what the 'unless' does in this piece of code. Looks extremely simple though.

```
  def self.tips_by_categories
    @categories = {}
    # Build up the possible categories
    Tip.all.each do |tip|
      tip.categories.each do |category|
        @categories[category.name] = [] unless @categories[category.name]
        @categories[category.name].push(tip)
      end
    end
    @categories
  end
```

Is it `@categories[category.name] = []` if `@categories[category.name]` is any string?

And if it isn't, what will `@categories[category.name]` end up being as a result (after the statement is executed)?

Comment: why is it using`@categories` instead of a local variable?

Comment: local variable is probably the better way to go. I don't believe there is any specific reason that the coder chose not to use local variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The line with the `unless` on it is equivalent to:

```
if !@categories[category.name]
  @categories[category.name] = []
end
```

If `@categories[category.name]` is nil or false, it changes it to the empty array `[]`.  Otherwise, it leaves it alone.

A much better way to have the same effect is to write:

```
@categories[category.name] ||= []
```

or to configure your hash table to have a default proc that returns `[]`.